Purpose of 了 in 还跑不跑了?
This is a dialogue from "New Practical Chinese Reader Vol. II":
A:咱们跑步跑了多长时间了？(How long have we been running?)
B:一个小时吧。(About an hour)
A:还跑不跑了？
B:再跑一会儿吧。
In the third line, I don't understand the purpose of 了。
If it was 还跑不跑? I was totally clear about it. "Shall we keep running or not?"
But 了 doesn't make sense to me in this sentence.

I would guess that the 了 echoes the previous answer and implies something like "Given that we have run for an hour, should we still run now?"

https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=3209   置於動詞後，表示動作的結束。

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/59349/use-of-%e4%ba%86-with-the-verb-%e6%80%95

在这里的了作为语气助词，可以省略掉，而句子的意思不变，即 还跑不跑了? is equal to 还跑不跑? (或还跑吗?)
其他了的用法可以看这个 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/59367/36261

A: 咱们跑步跑了多长时间了？
B:一个小时吧。
A: 还跑不跑了?
B:再跑一会儿吧。
According to Chinese Grammar Wiki there is an 了1:

Also known as:, verb 了, completed action 了 and perfective aspect 了
他们到了
They arrived / They have arrived

Preterite is basically a word form to indicate events in the past.

Preterite: from Latin praeteritum (as in tempus praeteritum "time
past"), past participle of praeterire "to go by, go past," from
praeter "beyond, over; more than" (see preter-) + itum, past
participle of ire "to go"

Roughly 1600 years ago, if became fashionable in Western languages to use a 2 part Compound Perfect Preterite instead of the existing Simple Perfect Preterite: use have with words that do not imply movement: I have eaten, use be with words that imply motion: I am come. This is still the case in German: Ich habe gegessen, Ich bin gekommen. English has, historically recently, dispensed with be forms and now only uses have: I have eaten, I have come. Spanish for I see is (yo) veo. Spanish still preserves both types of Preterite: Preterite Simple (Pretérito perfecto simple) vi, literally I seen and Preterite Compound (Pretérito perfecto compuesto) : I have seen, he visto
Chinese has no Preterite. You can translate 我到了 as: when I arrive, or, I arrived, or, I have arrived, always depending on the context.
Chinese Grammar Wiki says: 他们到了 = They have arrived
In that case, the translation of : 我到了给你打电话。（将来）should be:
"I have arrived, give you a call." NOT "I will call you when I get there."
Personally, I prefer the latter translation.
Chinese Grammar Wiki wants to extract itself from this unfortunate contradiction by saying: this is perfective aspect 了, which somehow is also the completed action 了， the了1.
Exactly what Chinese Grammar Wiki means by perfective aspect 了 is not clear to me, although I understand both words in the phrase well.
Chinese Grammar Wiki:

"了 (le) can appear in sentences about the future as well as the past.
What's important is whether or not the action has been completed, no
matter what time frame we're talking about."

Certainly, we can imagine that something, which has not yet happened, something in the future, has happened: 我到了，when I arrive, but actually, things can only happen NOW, unless you wish to think that all events past, present and future are happening now, which is a strange way of looking at time.
Or, 我到了 does not indicate completion. If not, what is 了？
Maybe it is Chinese Grammar Wiki:了2:

Also known as: change-of-state 了, sentence 了 and modal 了.

我饿了 = I hungry： I wasn't hungry. I am hungry now: change of state
我到了 = I (have）arrived: I wasn't there, I am now there: change of state
You can perhaps see the confusion.
Western style punctuation is relatively new to Chinese. Previously, words like 了 were used to separate phrases, to separate ideas. 了 still separates phrases and ideas. The Western style punctuation is superfluous：
A: 咱们跑步跑（了）多长时间（了）
A: us run steps run le much long time le
B:一个小时（吧）
B: one ge hour (ba)
还跑不跑（了） = 还继续跑 （吗）
A:还跑不跑 （了）（Don't need 了 here, you can equally not use 了 here)
A: still run (or) not run (le)
B:再跑一会儿 (吧)
B: Keep running a little while (ba)

I don't understand the purpose of 了

Personally, I regard 了 as "that". "that" is a name for something and anything. "that" is like a real, or, an imaginary finger, pointing at something:
He said that he had arrived
他说他已经到了
In English, that points forward. In Chinese, 了 points back and emphasises what has been said, or forward to something. Chinese has no Preterite. The time of an event is given by the context, not by 了.

It is clearly not a "completion" of action. The only choice is an indication of "a change of state".
The question consists of two parts, which can be considered as asking:

還跑嗎(current state)? 還是不跑了(new state)?


right, it's of the 下雨了 type: now I realize it is raining / it has started to rain
